# Xamarin Android save files, Environment.Specialfolder does not exist

Tags: android, xamarin.ios, storage

I just created an Xamarin Android Single-View-app, which downloads a file from dropbox. I earlier made this app, but my Mac's HDD crashed. I searched for the save-location and found:

```
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
var filename = Path.Combine(path, "newFile.png");
```

I tried it, but it was marked red, because it does not exist. I installed Xamarin yesterday, I have the latest version. I searched for hours, but i did not find a solution of the problem. Here are my "using's":

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try explicitly specifying the namespace, System.Environment.GetFolderPath() and System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData.  You may have a conflict between two different namespaces that both use "Environment"

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution!